# Why does my JavaScript event execute on any input, rather than input to the proper field in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an event I want to execute on key down in an input field. It does as much in Firefox. In chrome, however, it executes the event (a redirect) when I give the page any input (click, key down, etc). I can't seem to figure out why. Any ideas?

Here's the javascript:

```
var yum = document.getElementById("username");
var form = document.querySelector("div.resp-wrapper form[name='register']");
form.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
yum.addEventListener("keydown", function handler() {
    window.location.href = "https://giphy.com/gifs/troll-you-mad-face-eVy46EWyclTIA";
    this.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
});
```

This is the page I'm working on [Link Deleted]; you can see the problem there while it's live. I'll be removing this link eventually.

Oh I guess I should probably mention that this is an invisible form field (it's a honeypot). It's between the captcha and the last visible form field. You can run a test by clicking where the field would be and pressing any key.

**UPDATE**: I am able to reproduce on my Windows machine; chrome version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit). On my android, the behavior is the same as well (touching anywhere on the page redirects me) - version 74.0.3729.136. But was not able to reproduce on my Mac chrome version 71.0.3578.98.

Comment: it's actually a legit question. What are you seeing? This is a dev site. I have zero interest in people visiting it. But it's based on a framework (osclass) that a lot of people aren't familiar with, so it's easiest just to post a link here. I should say the code doesn't execute when expected. If you click, for example, home. The code executes. Or when you click register, the code executes. Sometimes just visiting the page, on load, the code executes. It should ONLY execute when you input into that invisible form field. It's actually to catch spammers; I assure you. This isn't spam.

Comment: "_In chrome, however, it executes the event (a redirect) when I load the page_" Can't reproduce. I navigate there in Chrome, no auto redirect.

Comment: Hmm. What are you seeing? Did it redirect you when you clicked the invisible form field I'm mentioning (I suppose it doesn't help perceptions that the redirect I'm currently using is a troll gif lol). It shouldn't redirect when clicking that field. It should only redirect if you keydown right now.

Comment: Yes, it worked as you described it should. Page loaded, I clicked the username textbox, then typed, then got redirected. (On Chrome 74.0.3729.131)

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's a issue with my chrome version? I've cleared cache a few times as well..(Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)). Looks like we're on the same one though.

Comment: After clearing my cache again and trying a few more times, it looks like the event fires if you click literally anywhere on the page for me; I think the page load redirects are just a result of caching the input from that first time.

Comment: How will this catch spammers? They don't execute the JavaScript, so they won't get redirected.

Comment: Eventually, I'll probably handle most of this with PHP. But that's irrelevant to my question.

Comment: You can try to add a `focus` event listener to all `<input>` with a `console.log(this)`, then you check the console.

Comment: I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out; and, of course, it was something stupid. I removed the CSS from the form field and realized that, even though I had cleared my cache and browser history, several times, that didn't prevent Chrome's autofill feature from populating that field EVERY time.

When I removed the CSS I could see the field was always populated whenever I visited the page. Chrome had been filling in my email address (oddly, considering it's not an email field). I cleared my Chrome autofill settings and now the code works as expected. It's unfortunate that the autocomplete="off" attribute doesn't prevent this. I've read that usually this attribute is moot because the [browser will override it anyway](https://www.20spokes.com/blog/what-to-do-when-chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off-on-your-form).